# Google Sheet : How to format line by line with a rule based on highest value on the line?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet like this one
[image]

with plenty of lines and different values on each line.

I have done rule to format the line 3 based on pourcentage of the highest value of the line.
It works for one line.

But if I copy paste this formatting rule to another line, the reference of the highest value is shared between all the lines who share the rule.

Example:
[image]

As you can see, now the 3 line colors are based on the highest value of line 2 and 3.

The rule is
[image]

What I want is to have the rule applied line by line. I can do manually. But I have 160 lines...

Is there a way to do that smartly ?

Thanks a lot

Bastien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column i in which you will calculate the maximum value of the current row. Then modify the conditional formatting to take this value into account for each row. Duplicate this conditional formatting if you want max, 90%, 75%.

For instance, column I contains the max value of each row.

The formula for conditional formatting is `=C2=$I2` for max value, nd `=C2>0.75*$I2` for values greater than 75% of max value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mike. I don't understand the second part of your solution. How can I change the conditionnal formatting for each row after having retrieved the max value of each line in a new column? I don't think you propose to do it manually. So, is it with a google apps script?

Comment: See the example inside my answer.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the update of your reply. It's a very smart way to do it. It works perfectly. Thanks a lot!